# jQuery - create flexible width on resize

Tags: jquery

i want to have flexible width , i mean when i try to resize window my windows width changes automatically ( based on window width ) without refresh

i want to do this in my sample document , how can i do this ?

my sample document :

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var Ww = $(window).width()
    var Wh = $(window).height()
    $('.test').css({"width":Ww+"px","height":Wh+"px"});
});
</script>
<style>
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.test {
    background-color:#000;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="test"></div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function resizer(){
    var Ww = $(window).width(),
        Wh = $(window).height();
    $('.test').css({width:Ww, height:Wh});
}

$(function(){ // DOM READY
    resizer();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    resizer();
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to use resizer in document.ready without problem ?

Comment: @AliM I don't think I understand your question. In my example you have the DOM ready function (just shortened)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this via CSS, no need of using jQuery for it.

```
.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

But if you still have any reason to do so via jQuery, you need to add the following function.

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function() {
    var Ww = $(window).width()
    var Wh = $(window).height()
    $('.test').css({"width":Ww+"px","height":Wh+"px"});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var Ww = $(window).width()
    var Wh = $(window).height()
    $('.test').css({"width":Ww+"px","height":Wh+"px"});
});
</script>
```

Comment: i dont want use css , because many actions in my pages are with jQuery

Comment: Well, if you insist, I've added the jQuery code as well. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but it works only when the page is resized
so when you run open page at first time without resizing , it shows nothing

Comment: You already have the "$(document).ready()" for that in your code. Do not remove it.

Comment: i used (document).ready() befor , but it's not working
`$(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).resize(function() {
  var Ww = $(window).width()
  var Wh = $(window).height()
  $('.test').css({"width":Ww+"px","height":Wh+"px"});
 });
});`

Comment: That isn't correct. I've edited my answer. That is how your script tag is supposed to look like.